# Google Pie Chart does not fit the container

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization, pie-chart

I am working with [Google Chart API](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/index) and have developed a pie chart with reference to 
[Visualization: Pie Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

Screenshot of my pie chart:-

[image: Chart]

Screenshot shows the container via firebug...

Here is the problem arises, the low opacity blue color is the container(i.e. div) in which the chart is appearing, some what it doesn't fit to that outer div in which its contained and showing some **useless whitespaces**, the pie chart should fit the div anyhow if my code is right...

Working on this code:-

```
var options_pie = {
chartArea: { left: 0, top: 0, width: "100%", height: "60%"},
colors: ['#59ea54', '#a14660', '#f3cf4a', '#16a2c2', '#ce7374', '#39ae9b'],
legend: 'none',
};

var chartPie = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_pie'));
chartPie.draw(data, options_pie);
```

I dont know, am i missing something or its the problem with the api?

Comment: Is it any different without the `left: 0`, and `top: 0;`?

Comment: @GusRuss89 Thanks for reply, that also tried, but no effect...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to modify width and height, for example :

```
 options.chartArea = {left:0, 'width': '80%', 'height': '80%'}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, their is 50% increment of the pie circle from the existing one after applying this code, do i keep both width and height 100% for that?

Comment: If you don't have legend, you could try 100%.

Comment: I had to make sure the container this chart was in was display: block first